# How to create a web service in Java that keeps push video binary data to a web page?

Tags: java, opencv, video, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have been doing researches on how to real-time stream video from a camera using Java and OpenCV. I could real-time stream the video with Java JFrame application.

Now I want to real-time stream the video on a web page. I have done researches on that. It seems that using `<video>` tag of HTML5 with `src="blob:http://domain.name/codeabcxxxxx"` is a good option.

So I've created a web service with Spring MVC framework. Below is the web service controller that handles the AJAX requests, captures the video frames from the camera and sends the AJAX response with the video frames in binary data.

```
import ...;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    final static int CV_CAP_DSHOW = 700;
    final static int CAMERA_ID = 0;

    VideoCapture videoCapture;
    Mat m;

    public GreetingController() {
        System.load( "C:\\opencv\\build\\java\\x64\\" + Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME + ".dll");
        
        videoCapture = new VideoCapture(CAMERA_ID, CV_CAP_DSHOW);
        m = new Mat();
        videoCapture.read(m);
   }

    @GetMapping("/streaming")
    public byte[] streaming() {
        while (true) {
          if (videoCapture.isOpened() && videoCapture.read(m)) {
            int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;

            if ( m.channels() > 1 ) {
                type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
            }

            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(m.width(), m.height(), type);
            WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
            DataBufferByte dataBuffer = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
            final byte[] targetPixels = dataBuffer.getData();
            m.get(0, 0, targetPixels);

            return targetPixels;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Besides that, I've created an `index.html` web page as following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Start Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <video id="second-video" controls  autoplay muted></video>
    <video id="third-video" controls  autoplay muted></video>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const secondVideo = document.getElementById("second-video");
    const thirdVideo = document.getElementById("third-video");
    const url = "http://localhost:8080/streaming";

    axios.get(url).then(res => {
        const content = res.data;
        // Try URL.createObjectURL
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content], {type: "video/H264"}));
        secondVideo.src = url;
        // Try MediaSource
        const mediaSourceA = new MediaSource(url);
        thirdVideo.srcObject = mediaSourceA ;
    });
</script>
</html>
```

The client (JavaScript on the web page) sends AJAX request to the web service, after getting AJAX response, containing the video frame in binary data, from the web service, it creates an blob object and add the object to the `src` attribute of the `<video>` tag. I have tried to use `URL.createObjectURL` and `MediaSource` for two different `<video>` tags. Nothing works!

Result: No video showing in the `<video>` tags and the web service does not keep sending next video frames, due to the `return` statement inside the `while-loop`.

I miss the following knowledge:

- Does the client need to keep sending AJAX requests to the web service for each video frame continuously?

or

- The client sends only one AJAX request and the web service keeps sending responses with new video frames continuously?
- If the client needs to keep sending AJAX requests, how does the client do that?
- If the client needs to send only one AJAX request, how can the web service keeps sending responses continuously? Because with my code above, the `while-loop` stops due to the `return` statement and the `streaming()` method needs to use the `return` statement.

I kind of miss some understanding, please help me! Thanks!

Comment: *this*: "The client sends only one AJAX request and the web service keeps sending responses with new video frames continuously"

Comment: "how can the web service keeps sending responses continuously" -- please research video streaming some more. HLS is the name of one method. there are others. use the term to start your research, but do branch out. I'm *not* claiming that specific term would be your solution.

Comment: I have inspected elements on the web pages of some television providers where people can watch real-time tv online, the web pages keeps sending AJAX requests continuously every 1 or 2 seconds. Are you sure that the client needs to send only one AJAX request?

Comment: NO AJAX AT ALL, in some technologies. because the browser is perfectly capable of reading the response from ONE HTTP REQUEST, which delivers one stream, and SHOW IT IN THE VIDEO TAG. without any javascript at all. none. just... do your research, and use existing libraries for both the browser-side and the server-side.